# How can I prevent to set a required recipient and the Open Graph object to appear?

Tags: embed, feed, yammer

I am currently trying to embed a Yammer Open Graph feed into SharePoint pages. I am using the following configuration:

`yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: "#embedded-feed"
    , feedType: "open-graph"
    , feedId: ""
    , config: {
        defaultGroupId: 27862       // recipient is required so I specified a dedicated group for article feeds
        //, use _ sso: true
        , header: false
        , footer: false
        , showOpenGraphPreview: false
        , defaultToCanonical: false
        , hideNetworkName: true
        , promptText: "What do you think of this article?"
    }
    , objectProperties: {
        url: ""     // <empty> takes the url from the current page
        , type: "page"
    }
});`

(feed configuration can be generated through https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure)

It seems that a recipient is required, so I had to create a dummy group and specify this dummy group-id where all the messages are landing. I don't want to polute some regular group with Open Graph object feeds. Can this be addressed in a better way?

Additionally, at least the first message contains the Open Graph object attached to it. This doesn't look nice, and is quite unnecessary as the feed is completely embedded onto the object already. Can this attachment be prevented? Moreover, as soon as you specify a calculated object url into the `objectProperties`, the object is attached to *all* messages. Which is completely overdone. Ideally the Open Graph object url is only used to identify the specific object feed.

Refer to the Facebook api where these two requirements are met: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Answer (score 0):

I think I have captured your questions below. Added my answer 
How can I prevent to set a required recipient?

You don't need to specify defaultGroupId. Adding this value simply changes the default Yammer group that the Embed Feed lists. 
From the documentation:
'You can set a default group for comments in an OGO Object Feed that will appear in the destination box of the publisher by specifying a defaultGroupId. The user can change this and post to a group of their choice.

If you do not specify a defaultGroupId, the destination box will be left blank and the user will be prompted to add a group on their own when posting a comment.

Specifying defaultGroupId: 0 will set the default to All Company.'
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/commenting

How can I prevent the Open Graph object to appear in the posting message window?

I am pretty sure this is by design. I can see how this can be confusing. I don't think there is a way to disable that.